# set UITableView image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to load locally stored images in a background thread and set them as UITableViewCell images. I keep getting an exception and don't really know how to approach it.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)loadImageInBackground:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *path = [[tableImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"png"]];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];

[img release];  
[pool release];
}

- (void) assignImageToImageView:(UIImage *)img
{

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:0];

((UIImageView *)cell.imageView).image = img;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks to all!

Comment: It crashes at ((UIImageView *)cell.imageView).image = img; saying that an unrecognised selector has been sent to the cell image view

Comment: Just put that error in your answer: copy+paste from the log

Comment: 2011-09-22 16:05:07.652 XH558[6563:13403] -[UITableView imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x82b5c00
2011-09-22 16:05:07.655 XH558[6563:13403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x82b5c00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mention in your error you are trying to set `image` to object of class `UITableView`. It is impossible.

In your code it is error here:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:0];
```

By default all views has default view `tag` set to `0`. When your are calling that method to your `tableView` it returns you first `UIView` with `tag == 0`. I think you didn't change default tag of your `UITableView *tableView` so that method returns you `tableView` and not `UITableViewCell`.

In this case, you need to choose right way to access appropriate `UITableViewCell *cell;`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to be a pain, but do you know how I would access the `UITableViewCell` properly and be able to set the image? thanks again